# Как изменить стиль всех контролов?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Сделала программу, в ней 70 разных контролов и все в стандартном стиле.

Как изменить стиль всех кнопок, форм memo, edit.... на те, **которые находятся в AlphaStandart** ?

Comment: Что такое "AlphaStandart "?

Comment: Это Компоненты скинменеджера.

Comment: Возможно вы имели в виду `Alpha Controls`. Если да, тогда Вам [сюда](http://www.alphaskins.com/showdoc.php?l=ru&n=6)